# How to create a program in C that compiles and runs another c program and saves the output in a txt file?

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I want to create a program in C such that it compiles another program of c and saves the output in a text file. For example, I want the output of my "input.c" file to be stored in a text file named "output.txt", using a C program. Please help. 
  I have chosen this project because it often becomes difficult to copy the entire output screen in Turbo C++, and sometimes turbo c doesn't show the entire output and only the current output screen is copied, leaving behind the previous output.

Comment: Is it C or C++ ? Pedantically, you cannot do that in portable C or portable C++ (because you cannot be guaranteed that the computer running your program has some compiler).

Comment: Does "the output in output.txt" refer to the diagnostic messages generated by the compiler during the compilation, or the output messages generated by the compiled program itself when you run it?  (either way, it sounds like running from the command line and redirecting stdout to a file with the > operator would get you what you want, with no programming required)

Comment: Please stop tag spamming C != C++ != C#. Use **only** the tags that actually apply to your question, and stop randomly adding others that just seem similar.

Comment: I compile (MSVC) from a console, using a batch file to ensure that environment variables are set. If the `errorlevel` is non-0 it recompiles with the compiler output redirected by `@NMAKE > TEMP.ERR` for the reasons you state: so I can examine the output more easily.

Comment: @KenWhite: What do you mean, “stop”? The OP has only two posted questions, and the other one was over a year ago and was not tagged with C or C++. They have not established any pattern of behavior to stop. Or do you imagine there is a massive organization of newbies colluding to enter questions with tags that irritate you, and that complaining to one of them will make the rest stop?

Comment: If I recall, TCC can be also be run from a console.

Comment: You do not need a C program to compile and run another program and save its output. If you could do it in a C program, you could do it from the command line shell (except in some bizarre cripped GUI-only system). So really all you need to know is the commands to compile using your C compiler and to run a program and redirect its output to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You either run a shell command that compiles and runs your subprogram (`man 3 system`, easy), or you go with more advanced techniques such as on-the-fly compilation (http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/On-the-fly-C++/ or https://bellard.org/tcc/ if you're a C programmer)

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the Standard C functions named `system()` and POSIX `popen()`.

On a POSIXly system with a C compiler, to compile a simple C program would be

```
system("cc -o input input.c");
```

And to run it and capture the output,

```
FILE *fp_in = popen("./input", "r"); /* to read */
FILE *fp_out = fopen("output.txt", "w"); /* to write */
```

Then read from `fp_in` and write to `fp_out`. That's the basic idea. I've left the details for you to figure out, so you gain deep insight into deep C secrets :-)
Don't forget the error handling for all library functions.

PS: If the system's shell supports redirection, you might even simplify the popen/fopen combo to a single `system("./input > output.txt");`

PPS: If the `PS` works, you might as well combine everything into `system("cc -o input input.c && ./input > output.txt");` I trust you know how to wrap this in `main()`.

Comment: AFAIK, `popen` is not in the C11 standard (but only in POSIX)

Answer (score 0):

The C11 standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) *does not define* how to run a compiler. In many cases (think about cross-compiling for some [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) target) you won't be able to run a compiler on the target machine (it could be "too small").

BTW, you could compile your code into some executable, remove every compiler from your system, and run that executable (in a situation where your system don't have any compiler)....

The C11 standard vaguely speaks in §7.22.4.8 of a `system` function.

On some implementations, that `system` function is able to start *other* programs (in processes) thru some *unspecified* command processor. But there is no guarantee that you'll be able to start a *compiler* (for example, you could run your executable on a Windows computer without any compiler).

<sup>(In practice, your computer is likely to practically have some command line C compiler, but you need to know which one and how to invoke it)</sup>

[On POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48548412/841108), you could use [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) (which uses `/bin/sh -c`), but also [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) -and other functions, e.g. [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)- to start other programs.

On Linux, you usually have some *command line* compiler, often [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc` (or even `cc`). You could run it (e.g. using `system`).

I like to do the following trick on my Linux system: generate some *temporary* file containing C code, e.g. `/tmp/temporaryc.c`, then compile that temporary file into some temporary [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) `/tmp/temporaryplugin.so` by using `system` with a command (in a string built at runtime) like `gcc -Wall -O -fPIC -shared /tmp/temporaryc.c -o /tmp/temporaryplugin.so`, and at last [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) that plugin using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).

Look also into [JIT-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries like [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/).

BTW, you should consider giving up Turbo C (it is an obsolete compiler for obsolete variants of C or C++) and switch to Linux on your PC.